# Styling notification style like music player android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

How to make custom layout for android notification. Just like android's music player that have buttons, cover image in its notification music. Do you have idea? Can you give an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made custom notification for my music player app.
First create an notification_expanded.xml which can be used for Android Lollipop and above

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/notificationbg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="125dp"
android:background="#212121"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/status_bar_album_art"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_expanded_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_expanded_height"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/status_bar_collapse"/>

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@id/status_bar_collapse"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

 </RevaliveLayout>
```

The above code is just random. You can put anything you want in there for when  the notification is fully expanded like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNo26.jpg).

Then create a notification_small_view.xml to show when the notification is small.

In your service which starts the notification set the appropriate big view and small view.

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification_small_view);
RemoteViews bigViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification_expanded);
```

Set data dynamically in your expanded or small notification like this.

```
bigViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, songTitle);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.status_bar_track_name, songTitle);
```

Then set these layouts to your notification.

```
Notification notification.contentView = views;
notification.bigContentView = bigViews;
```